# Why did Grocer fire on NSA agents instead of Blank when the agents showed up during their shootout?

Tags: plot-explanation, grosse-pointe-blank

At the climax of *Grosse Point Blank*, Martin Blank and Grocer are exchanging shots in the kitchen of Bart and Debi's home.

Two NSA agents (Lardner and McCullers) show up, intending to kill Blank (as Grocer asked them to do).

Seeing how the agents were working with Grocer, who invited them so they could kill Blank for him, **I would have expected Grocer to use the distraction and shoot Blank**.

Instead, Grocer joins Blank in killing the agents, happily yelling "Workers of the world, UNITE!" and ending up with empty clips.

## Why did Grocer help Blank shoot the agents instead of helping the agents shoot Blank?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/grosse_point_blank.html) suggests that he killed them on instinct. Lardner and McCullers break in guns blazing, yelling and firing indiscriminately. Grocer returned fired on them *because they were shooting at him*.

> NT. NEWBERRY FOYER - CONTINUOUS
>
> MARTIN reaches the top of the front stairs to find Grocer heading up the stairs at him. They lift their guns at each other to FIRE, when they hear...
>
> LARDNER AND MCCULLERS power through the front door, guns BLAZING at floor-level, ala Butch and Sundance.
>
> Martin and Grocer, above, spin on them instinctively, and FIRE, killing them. Grocer dives off of the stairs and rolls out of view.

Note that in the film the schtick here is that he's not actually wanting to kill Martin. He wants him to join his contract-killer's union, hence the line about the [workers of the world uniting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workers_of_the_world,_unite!). He's highlighting that they just worked together to stick it to 'the man'.